# MATLAB exercise for average of dot products of unit vectors not matching textbook's calculus result.

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab

I'm working through Strang's *Introduction to Linear Algebra*. Problem Set 1.2, #34 states,

> Using $v=randn(3,1)$ in MATLAB, create a random unit vector $u=\frac{v}{||v||}$. Using $V=randn(3,30)$ create 30 more random unit vectors $U_j$. What is the average size of the dot products $|u\cdot U_j|$? In calculus, the average is $\int_0^\pi |\cos\theta| d\theta / \pi = 2/\pi$.

Here's my program:

```
v=randn(3,1)
u=v/norm(v)
sum=0
k=30
for i=1:k
    V=randn(3,1)
    U=V/norm(V)
    dot_product=abs(dot(u,U));
    sum+=dot_product;
end
sum/k
```

I am getting an average near $1/2$, not $2/\pi$. Same tendency as I increase `k` tenfold or hundredfold.

Sample output of my program below. The unit vectors look correct. Is there something I'm misunderstanding?

```
v =

  -0.9049
   0.4694
  -1.0034

u =

  -0.6326
   0.3281
  -0.7015

sum = 0
k = 30
V =

   0.443107
   0.064042
   0.274244

U =

   0.8440
   0.1220
   0.5223

...
...
...

V =

  -0.6647
   0.5873
  -0.9252

U =

  -0.5186
   0.4582
  -0.7219

ans = 0.5125
```

Comment: After a quick check. Did you think of the fact that when V is a matrix the definition of norm changes? You want to use a norm that is that of a vector for each column. There could be other things wrong but this stood out to me,

Comment: @Jap88 - Thanks! Hm, I could be wrong, but I think this problem doesn't really have much to do with matrices—it's just using one as shorthand to generate many vectors.

Comment: I've added a line `check_unity=sqrt(U(1)^2+U(2)^2+U(3)^2)` to check that they're all unit vectors, which suggests that `norm` is doing what I want it to. (They all output 1.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral looks very much like the 2D version where the angle between the two vectors is uniformly distributed between $0$ and $\pi$. Indeed if you do the Matlab exercise with "rand(2,1)" you get close to $2/\pi$.

Looks like an error in the book.

Comment: Thanks! Ah, that's kind of interesting then that the "3D" version averages at $1/2$. Would this 3D version be like a half shell (half sphere)? Or maybe it's more complicated.